# Android-java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android, ocr

I'm making a image-to-text Android app and am trying to take text from gallery image using tess-two library .i am using github code like this link "https://github.com/TheWall89/AndrOCR".

I looked at a some of error in AndrOCR ShowImage.java.

Here's my Logcat results:

```
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    ... 11 more
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at com.matpergo.androcr.ShowImage.initTess(ShowImage.java:241)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at com.matpergo.androcr.ShowImage$OCR.onPreExecute(ShowImage.java:654)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at com.matpergo.androcr.ShowImage.startOCR(ShowImage.java:259)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    ... 14 more
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load lept: findLibrary returned null
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:44)
08-12 10:25:02.269: E/AndroidRuntime(22697):    ... 19 more
08-12 10:25:04.033: I/Process(22697): Sending signal. PID: 22697 SIG: 9
```

i think error should be in below code of showImage class.

// Library initialization

```
public void initTess() {
    if (mBaseApi != null)
        mBaseApi.end();

    mBaseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    mBaseApi.setDebug(false);
    mBaseApi.setPageSegMode(mSegMode);
    mBaseApi.init(mDataDir + File.separator, mLang,
            TessBaseAPI.OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY);
    // Log.w(TAG, "initTess executed: " + mSegMode + "," + mLang);
}
```

Comment: Post your activity and xml code

Comment: do you have the JAR added to the libs folder, added to project build path in libraries, and ticked for Order and Export?

Comment: i think problem with build ndk. so i will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the logs it looks like system is unable to find `.so` native libs. Check whether you've properly copied those